# Really old question draft appears in Safari after machine restart

Tags: support, draft, browsers

After doing a lot of editing yesterday and today in the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) *Ask a Question* box on Safari, when I absentmindedly restarted my laptop ([MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro)) without thinking about the possible consequences, Safari put a really old draft in the textbox and all my recent editing appears to be lost forever.

This naturally leads me to wonder what good "Draft saved" is.  I usually copy/paste into a [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad) document after every new sentence, but I fell out of the habit with this recent editing.  Fortunately, I didn't lose that much, but it's hard to remember exactly what I wrote.

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine if what you saw was data stored by Safari that was restored upon restart or of it's actually a new page load that pulled in the draft that was saved on SE. If it was just Safari restoring what was in the textbox, then it's possible that Safari, or you editing it, then overwrote whatever was stored on SE's servers.

Comment: Not sure it was worth it but rewriting from memory produced a version that is better than any of the pervious ones.

Comment: @Makyen a possible complicating factor is I had two or three tabs open on the same Math SE Ask a Question page.  Safari loaded one of those older ones, as I mentioned.  Anyway I'm saving to Notepad now and restored my work from memory so it was no great loss thankfully.  It would be good if all auto draft saves were accessible from our profile page but I guess that might take up too much disk space.

Comment: Lesson learned: Safari is a bad browser, Edge all the way.